# search and replace in vi (woth TAB & SPACE & new line)

Tags: search, replace, vi

I have one file and would like to do search and replace – as shown

My_name group_1 \ (TAB)(SPACE)

(TAB)(SPACE)       -class { student_1 }

My_name group_2 \ (TAB)(SPACE)

(TAB)(SPACE)       -class { student_1 }

My_name group_3 \ (TAB)(SPACE)

(TAB)(SPACE)       -class { student_3 }

Please note that – before ‘-class’ there is TAB and SPACE

I am using vi.  From above strings would like to do something like this –

My_name group_1        -class { student_1 }

My_name group_2        -class { student_1 }

My_name group_3        -class { student_3 }

I tried search and replace with   :%s, selected the entire file and did - :s/..

But no success.  Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First replace all tab with a single space using the below command:

```
1,$s/\t/ /g
```

Next, search for two spaces followed by a newline and remove them.

```
1,$s/  \n//g
```

If there are any more trailing spaces, you can remove them by :

```
s/ \{2,}/ /g
```

The last command would replace 2 or more spaces with a single space.